# How to preview Markdown in a Vim buffer?

Tags: vim-windows, filetype-markdown, previewing

I'm aware of some of the Markdown plugins for Vim, but I want the functionality VS Code and Atom provide, namely being able to split the editor screen and render a live Markdown preview in an adjacent buffer/frame, rather than in a browser.

Is this possible with Vim?

Comment: Vim is a text-editor, so it’s not (natively) capable of displaying rendered/rich text. What’s usually done is a pdf viewer or web-browser—I’m not aware of any way to display a richly formatted markdown document directly in a vim buffer.